# Excel corruption with VBA sorting records

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with a macro that filters records. After running the macro I save and close the file. Once I open the file again it says that the file has been corrupted:

> Excel found unreadable content in '[filename].xls'.
>   Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?
>   If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

Once I click Yes the file opens and looking at the XML file that directs me to I find the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <logFileName>error050360_01.xml</logFileName>
    <summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\xxx\file.xlsb'</summary>
    <removedRecords summary="Following is a list of removed records:">
        <removedRecord>Removed Records: Sorting from /xl/worksheets/sheet11.bin part</removedRecord>
    </removedRecords>
</recoveryLog>
```

On Sheet11 I have the following sorting code:

```vb
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A3").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AP_PV").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AP_PV").Sort.SortFields.Add key:=Range("A4:A" & LastRow) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AP_PV").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A3:B" & LastRow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

I tried adding a condition before `Range("A3").Select` to see if `LastRow > 4` to exclude the sorting, but id didn't make any difference.

Any ideas on what is causing the corruption and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd comment this, simply providing the link, but I don't have 50 reputation yet.

A Google search turned up an SE thread from a few years ago with plenty of possible solutions: [Excel Error: Removed Records: Sorting from /xl/worksheets/sheet10.xml part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561870/excel-error-removed-records-sorting-from-xl-worksheets-sheet10-xml-part)

Most likely to work is this one:

```
Sheets(yoursheetname).Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

Put that after your sort function (or before saving your file), and it seems the issue should be resolved.

Hopefully that works.

When a SortFields.Add2 Key uses an ordinary Range (eg Range("B2:B100"), this error does not occur.
However, It seems this error always occurs when a variable has been used to set the Range for the SortFields.Add2 Key.
The solution offered above works - but only necessary when using a variable.
Since this line is not included (at the end) when using the macro recorder, I think it qualifies as a bug.

Comment: Same issue, fixed by this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error tells it is "sheet11" and you could copy the content to a new workbook, delete the sheet in the error work book and create a new sheet with the content

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in Office 365 Excel for Windows. I was applying the sort to a worksheet object, but I failed to deallocate the object at the end of the sub.  Once I added the **set ws = nothing** code to the end of the sub, the problem stopped occurring.  I also cleared the sort fields as suggested earlier, but only after adding the deallocation code did this stop entirely.

Deallocation is always good practice. We often hear that the objects are dropped when they go out of scope, but that is not always the case.