# Why does my .XLSM file get corrupted when using VBA to sort a Range?

Tags: excel, vba

**Description Of Problem:**

I have a range in excel that I'd like to automatically sort by two levels. First by  column q reverse alphabetically, then by column d alphabetically from row 7 to last row. I have tried to sort this manually, however each attempt brings me this error:

> To do this, all the merged cells need to be the same size.

The range I am attempting to sort begins at B7 and goes all the way to R-LastRow. Each merged cell is the same size in their respective column:

-**Columns 'D:I'** are merged for each row in the range

-**Columns 'K:L'** are merged for each row in the range

-**Columns 'N:O'** are merged for each row in the range

-**Columns 'Q:R'** are merged for each row in the range

**What I have tried:**

-Unmerging columns 'Q' and 'R' and attempting to only sort by column 'Q'

-Attempted to sort with VBA with the following code:

```
With ActiveSheet.Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Q7"), Order:=xlDescending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D7"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SetRange Range("B7", Range("R7").End(xlDown))
     .Header = xlYes
     .Apply
End With
```

This macro performed what I needed done flawlessly, however once I close down the file and reopen, I think it becomes corrupted. I get the following message:

> We found a problem with some content in 'Manager Search.xlsm'. Do you
>   want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source
>   of this workbook, click Yes.

Upon clicking yes then I can only access the file as 'Read-Only' because it says the file is in use by 'Another User' (the file is on a server). After opening read only I get this message:

[image]

After clicking close the problem is reoccurring because it is read only. So I move it to my desktop locally, repair it, and the problem reoccurs anytime i run the code.

What am I doing wrong? I'd prefer to sort through VBA.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/42999112/11683 help?

Comment: what if you remove all the merged cells? And add `.SortFields.Clear` to the beginning of your with block?

Comment: The .SortFields.Clear at the end of my code helped, thanks GSerg and Scott