# My Excel VBA sorting code errors and requires manual saving

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a spreadsheet using two sort routines:

```
   Sub Sort_Date_From_To()

   Range("A3:Q10000").Sort Key1:=Range("C3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("F3"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("F3"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

    End Sub
    Sub Sort_From_To_Date()

    Range("A3:Q10000").Sort Key1:=Range("F3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("G3"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("C3"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

    End Sub
```

The sort functions perfectly butspreadsheet saves normally but a dialog display and with a log link.  Following the link has this text:

xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">error098840_01.xmlErrors were detected in file 'F:\xxxxx - Distribution - Copy.xlsm'Removed Records: Sorting from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

Can someone give me insight to this?  It is the second time I have run into a VBA sort routine which throws such an error.

Thank you

Comment: Could be the same issue like (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561870/excel-error-removed-records-sorting-from-xl-worksheets-sheet10-xml-part). So try clearing the sort fields